# simple cursor adapter requires minimum api 11 issue

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I am working on a app , in which i require to populate list view from the database. I am getting compatibility issue in following code

```
   dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this, R.layout.eventlisting, 
    cursor, 
    columns, 
    to,
    0);
```

It requires min api level 11 , mine is 8. Is there any alternative for this to make this code work on api 8 as well. Can i use support library?

Comment: The support library has the `SimpleCursorAdapter` that you look for.

Comment: @user1918034 have u download Support Library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the [SimpleCursorAdapter from the support class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html). It is used like the API 11+ version and it is already backwards compatible.

You have to download the Support Library , so you only need to change the import Like This way
:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Backword compatibility you can download support library and make your Code working.

to add support library

Right Click your Project -> android tools -> add support library.

then again

Right Click your Project -> android tools -> fix project properties.

and then clean build your project.after that you will be able to import SimpleCursorAdapter class in your application.hope it will help.