# Custom Listview from SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

In My app minimum SDK is API 9: Android 2.3 (Gingerbread).All functionalities are working fine both on a virtual device(running Android 6.0 Marshmallow) and a real device (Huawei Y210 with Android 2.3 Gingerbread).

The problem is when I add a custom listview that populates data from an SQLite database, the app crashes on the real device but runs fine on the virtual device.

I noticed that I had to add **import android.annotation.TargetApi** to clear an error from `SimpleCursorAdapter`

**Here is the snippet**

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void populateListVew(){
        Cursor cursor  = myDB.getAllMembers();
        String[] dbValues = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.COL_1,DatabaseHelper.COL_2,DatabaseHelper.COL_3, DatabaseHelper.COL_4};
        int[] viewIds = new int[] {R.id.memberId, R.id.membersName,R.id.nickName, R.id.mobileNumber};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.member_listview, cursor,dbValues,viewIds,0);
        allMembers.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }
```

I have gone through several similar questions but none seems to have the TargetApi issue.

Is there a better option to make this work for Android 2.3 too? Please suggest me.

Comment: You have set  `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
` i.e. 3.0 and minimum API level to use  `SimpleCursorAdapter `  is 11. So refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/14291024/3817374 to support same in lower version

Comment: Thanks @Beena. The answer from that link worked for me

Comment: You are always welcome...  :)

Comment: Also mind that API Level 9 is no longer supported by Google. While API Level 8 still is. Weird, uh? For your reference: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Really weird. Thanks for the info though.